# Homotopy Lemma for an abelian category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation

I'm new in the category theory and I don't know if this is out of topic, but can someone recommend me a book where I can find the proof of the Homotopy Lemma for an abelian category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just googling with 'abelian category homotopy lemma' in google books give me [an answer](https://books.google.com/books?id=yMz9fW8JgiwC&pg=PA381) to your question in a second.

Comment: Thank you! My google results didn't show me this result